# Wi-fi connection established - but no internet

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and trying to connect to my WIFI. But not able to connect to Internet.

While searching for solutions i Found posts [like][1] and changed the setting like that still no use.

How can I connect to the Internet via WIFI?

Comment: Please note that both ethernet and wireless are connected and have IP addresses. Please detach the ethernet, reboot and tell us if there is any improvement. If not, please let us have a new paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your wireless info, we see that you have both ethernet and wireless connected. Network Manager defaults to ethernet, if available, as it is generally faster and more secure. Reboot with the ethernet detached before we proceed.

We also see:

```
wlx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"D-Link_DIR-816"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'D-Link_DIR-816' [AC1]>   
          Bit Rate:150 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode:open
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/100  Signal level=7/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

When an encryption key is shown (and redacted by the wireless script), it implies that the encryption mode is WEP. However, your access point uses WPA2-AES (often also referred to as CCMP):

```
Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'D-Link_DIR-816' [AC1]>
                    ESSID:"D-Link_DIR-816"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Encryption key:on
                    Bit Rates:300 Mb/s
                    Extra:rsn_ie=30140100000fac040100000fac040100000fac020000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    Quality=0/100  Signal level=5/100
```

This suggests that there may be a mismatch in your Network Manager settings. Please click the Network Manager icon, select Edit Connections, and select Wi-Fi Security and be certain that Security is set to WPA & WPA2 Personal.

Restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Next, you have two drivers attempting to load and possibly conflict:

```
[   14.848894] r8188eu: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   15.154448] 8188eu: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   15.155495] Error: Driver 'r8188eu' is already registered, aborting...
```

I suggest that you blacklist one and test:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist 8188eu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r 8188eu
exit
```

Reboot with the ethernet detached and test:

```
ping -c3 192.168.0.1
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

If you get ping returns from all three, you are all set.

Comment: Thanks this worked and iam able to connect to internet with wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Try this driver instead of staging. lwfinger has had a lot of success with his drivers.

be sure you have git and dkms:  `sudo apt-get install git dkms`

then `git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu`

Remove the old drivers.
open a terminal in the folder just created and type:

```
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188eu  
sudo dkms build 8188eu/1.0  
sudo dkms install 8188eu/1.0
```

Copy the firmware (rtl8188eufw.bin) to /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
and reboot.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. Copy the firmware (rtl8188eufw.bin) to /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/ - did not understood how to do this. Iam a very basic ubuntu user.

Comment: if missing yes and reboot. if it doesn't work remove the staging version and build this one from source.

Comment: After runnung the commands and rebooting also nothing changed.

Comment: you removed the old driver, the driver installed? and you copied the firmware over? please rerun the commands a post the info for the card state

Comment: that is just the firmware, you have to create the driver by typing the commands indicated, remove the old driver first

Comment: How does he 'remove the old driver first'? Please provide instructions. Why do you believe that the 4 year old driver at git is better than the in-kernel r8188eu?

Comment: @chili555 -- he removes the the same way he installed them from staging

Comment: His most recent paste shows the old driver loaded and not the new.

Comment: because he didn't follow the directions, just jumped to the last step (copying the firmware)

Comment: Your directions simply say: "Remove the old drivers." What is the exact procedure? The dkms process will not do it as the paste shows clearly.

Comment: @chili555 -- depends how he installed it

Comment: If he installed the git driver exactly as you instructed, it did not and will not "remove the old driver." I am quite confident the the old driver, as you refer to it, is actually *newer* and is the default in-kernel driver. He installed it by simply installing Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 -- exactly which is why I told him to remove the old driver.  if you read his comments you will see he neither installed the git driver nor removed tho old one, all he did was jump to the bottom and copy the firmware.  why do you continue this circular  discussion??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61872/discussion-between-chili555-and-ravery).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestions too..actually iam a very basic user and do not have much knowledge about networking and also about ubuntu.

Comment: ok, so how did you install the staging drivers? you have to remove them